# Chnage location of hive managed table after creation

Tags: hive, hdfs

I have created a managed table.now i want to change the default location of the table to non hdfs location
i tried the below command but not working

ALTER TABLE my_table SET LOCATION "/path/to/file"

Comment: what non hdfs location are you attempting to use ? You generally need to specify an absolute path such as "s3://" or "hdfs://"